# How to design Java server with NIO?

Tags: java, sockets, concurrency, network-programming, nio

Suppose I am writing a server. The server accepts clients connections, reads requests from the network, process them and sends back the results. Suppose also that I would like to handle all that socket stuff manually (just as an exercise).

I would like to have a single thread to handle sockets with `java.nio` non-blocking API. When it reads a request completely it starts processing it *asynchronously* (using `Future` or passing the request to another thread) and returns to the `selector` immediately.

When the processing finishes the "socket thread" should receive the response to send it back over the sockets to the client. However I do not see how to do that.

Does it mean that the design above is wrong ? How would you suggest implement the server with `java.nio` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a request is put in the queue, and the selector thread is in `selector.select()`, call `selector.wakeup()`. The selector thread executes loop like this:

```
while (selector.isOpen() && !Thread.interrupted()) {
    for (;;) {
        Request r=queue.poll(); // requests can be both to read and write
        if (r==null) {
            break;
        }
        processRequest(r);
    }

    selector.select(); // wait for next event

    // Iterate over the set of keys for which events are available
    Iterator<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
    while (selectedKeys.hasNext()) {
        SelectionKey key = selectedKeys.next();
        selectedKeys.remove();
        processKey(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! `selector.wakeup` seems to be the API I was looking for.